# Extrating image information about a PNG in .NET

Tags: c#, image, metadata

I'm trying to get information about a PNG file but I've yet to discover a comprehensive site to help me.

These are some of the semi useful code snippets I have:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pngFileName);
BitmapData bd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
```

and

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(pngFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
```

With these I've been able to to get the image height and width. However I still need to discover the following information:

- Is it RLE encoded?
- Is it in native video format?
- Is it rotated?
- Does it use a grayscale palette?
- Does it have a transparency?
- Is it RGB or BGR?

I'd really appreciate some pointers on how to acheive this or links to good articles dealing with this. We're working with .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that helps you, but the best I've seen so far, is to walk the image pixel by pixel in a loop and accomplish your different tasks.

See these answers for examples:

- [Detecting if a PNG image file is a Transparent image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569538/detecting-if-a-png-image-file-is-a-transparent-image/2570002#2570002)
- [Detecting grayscale images with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877405/detecting-grayscale-images-with-net/1877420#1877420)